# Extract parts of border property in SASS

Tags: css, split, sass, border

Given a valid CSS border property value in a SASS variable (code in scss syntax) I need to know the width as well as the color of the given border.

This could be done using a `@function` as I need this functionality multiple times.

The inputs could look like the following (it does not matter if one of the border properties is missing, as this is still valid CSS):

- `2px dashed white`
- `1px #333`
- `solid black`

Unfortunately I do not even know where to start.
I wanted to split up the list and then return the according value, but I do not know how to determine the different types, e.g. how do I know its the border-width value?

---

Thats where I am currently stuck:

```
@function getBorderWidth($border) {
    @each $part in $border {
        @if(WHAT IS THE CONDITION?) {
            return $part;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for **type-of($part):**

```
@if type-of($part) == number { @return $part; }
@if type-of($part) == string { @return $part; }
@if type-of($part) == color  { @return $part; }
```

Example:

```
// Note! the null return will not be rendered 
@function get-border-width($input){
  @each $part in $input { @if type-of($part) == number { @return $part; } }   
  @return null;
}
@function get-border-style($input){
  @each $part in $input { @if type-of($part) == string { @return $part; } }   
  @return null;    
}
@function get-border-color($input){
  @each $part in $input { @if type-of($part) == color { @return $part; } }   
  @return null;    
}
```

Test:

```
$border-1: 2px dashed white;
$border-2: 1px #333;
$border-3: solid black;

test-1 {
  border-width: get-border-width($border-1);
  border-style: get-border-style($border-1);    
  border-color: get-border-color($border-1);    
}

test-2 {
  border-width: get-border-width($border-2);
  border-style: get-border-style($border-2);    
  border-color: get-border-color($border-2);    
}

test-3 {
  border-width: get-border-width($border-3);
  border-style: get-border-style($border-3);    
  border-color: get-border-color($border-3);    
}
```

Output:

```
test-1 {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-color: white;
}

test-2 {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #333;
}

test-3 {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate the use case? SASS is not meant for such manipulations and they are required only when you're writing a library/framework on top of SASS e.g. something like compass.

Btw you can do it this way

```
$border: 2px dashed white;
@function getBorderWidth($border) {
    @each $part in $border {
      @if (str-slice(inspect($part),-2,-1) == "px") {
        @return $part
      }
    }
}
```

Explanation

`inspect` converts each part to string and `str-slice` slice the last 2 characters.

Working demo: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/00b0cf21a7ddeed282015d1c8ce74e0d